# Issues exporting large amounts of animations to Unity

Tags: animation, export, unity, nla-editor

I'm having a few issues I have been trying to work around for a few months now when I'm trying to export a large group of animation Actions or NLA animations.

When I try exporting all my actions into an .fbx, my animations look more accurate, but I'm missing a lot of animations.

Anim List Blender:

[image]

Anim List Unity:

[image]

Next I tried loading all my animations in NlaTracks (I tried exporting with all of the animations in one track, and each animation in their own track) I noticed that all my animations were in the list, but then I came across another issue where the first couple frames were the same pose as the previous animation(This happened when setting my ActionExtrapolation to Hold, Hold Forward, and Nothing).

What it looks like in blender
https://media.giphy.com/media/xT0xey9xLaLvmpdbBS/giphy.gif

What it looks like in Unity
https://media.giphy.com/media/l4EoOHU033sfvkZgY/giphy.gif

Also, This wierdness happened with NLA exporting. And it happens no mater how I bake all the frames. The only thing that seems to fix this is if I make it the first animation in my NlaTrack list.

Original:
https://media.giphy.com/media/xT0xeoWNDS87p5p3Es/giphy.gif

Unity:
https://media.giphy.com/media/3o6nUN4AgEKu7cOxvG/giphy.gif